# Добавление параметра к свойству

Tags: c#, параметры, свойства

Суть вопроса в том, что я получаю набор шестнадцатеричных данных в формате string.
пример:

```
string dataLine = "63EDF9AC00028702F60303040800000203096000210102805000010012650309000";
```

Данных много, dataLine представлена не полностью.

Для начала, я перевожу dataLine в List, группируя по 2 символа:

```
var data = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 2; i < dataLine.Length / 2; i += 2)
    {
        data.Add(dataLine.Substring(0, 2));

        dataLine = dataLine.Substring(2);
    }
```

Мне нужно эти данные привести к свойствам модели. Но каждое свойство имеет разную длину в байтах.
Например первые 3 из них:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// UNIX-штамп обновления пакета в секундах (с первого января 1970г.)
    /// Тип: 8 Целое число, беззнаковое, 4 байта
    /// Позиция: 0
    /// Количество символов: 8 
    /// </summary>
    public int PackTime { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Номер пакета (0 - данные телеметрии)
    /// Тип: Целое число, беззнаковое, 1 байт
    /// Позиция: 8
    /// Количество символов: 2 
    /// </summary>
    public int PackNo { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Позиция: 10
    /// Количество символов: 4 
    /// </summary>
    public int SW { get; set; }
```

Есть мысль получать все свойства модели через:

```
var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
```

И в цикле перебирая свойства присваивать им значения, на основании количества символов.
и каждый раз удалять элементы из data,опять же согласно (количества символов)/2.

Можно ли как то добавить что то типа параметра к свойству?

Использовал вариант с кастомным атрибутом, но я не знаю на сколько это костыльно:

```
internal class SymbolCountAttribute : Attribute
{
    private int SymbolCount;
    public SymbolCountAttribute(int symbolCount)
    {
        SymbolCount = symbolCount;
    }
}

    /// <summary>
    /// UNIX-штамп обновления пакета в секундах (с первого января 1970г.)
    /// Тип: 8 Целое число, беззнаковое, 4 байта
    /// Позиция: 0
    /// Количество символов: 8 
    /// </summary>
    [SymbolCount(8)]
    public int PackTime { get; set; }
```

Данные по атрибуту получаю следующим образом:

```
foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
         var value = prop.CustomAttributes.First().ConstructorArguments.First().Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я вам уже [давал ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1523212/373567) на вопрос про сериализацию.

Не надо никаких аттрибутов, надо сделать модель с типами, которые соответствуют данным, вот например так.

```
class MyModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// UNIX-штамп обновления пакета в секундах (с первого января 1970г.)
    /// Тип: 8 Целое число, беззнаковое, 4 байта
    /// Позиция: 0
    /// Количество символов: 8 
    /// </summary>
    public uint PackTime { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Номер пакета (0 - данные телеметрии)
    /// Тип: Целое число, беззнаковое, 1 байт
    /// Позиция: 8
    /// Количество символов: 2 
    /// </summary>
    public byte PackNo { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Позиция: 10
    /// Количество символов: 4 
    /// </summary>
    public ushort SW { get; set; }
}
```

Не надо выдумывать своих преобразователей 16-ричной записи, они уже есть встроенные в .NET. Возьму к примеру только данные из начала строки, соответствующие суммарной длине ваших свойств.

```
string dataLine = "63EDF9AC000287";
Span<byte> data = Convert.FromHexString(dataLine);
```

И далее просто распарсить например используя рефлексию.

```
int index = 0;
MyModel model = new MyModel();
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(MyModel).GetProperties())
{ 
    switch (prop.GetValue(model))
    {
        case uint:
            prop.SetValue(model, BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt32BigEndian(data[index..]));
            index += sizeof(uint); // 4
            break;
        case byte:
            prop.SetValue(model, data[index]);
            index++;
            break;
        case ushort:
            prop.SetValue(model, BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16BigEndian(data[index..]));
            index += sizeof(ushort); // 2
            break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(model));
Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(model.PackTime));
```

Вывод в консоль

```
{"PackTime":1676540332,"PackNo":0,"SW":647}
16.02.2023 09:38:52 +00:00
```

Comment: Приветствую, у меня пока мало опыта, поэтому даже эти 2 задачи кажутся мне разными. Да, Ваш способ помог. я правильно понимаю, для адекватного заполнения свойств они должны идти в том порядке (в описании модели) в котором приходят в строке?

Comment: Могли бы мне прояснить некоторые моменты? мне понятна запись [index..] конкретно 2 точки. и почему 4 символа соответствует uint, а не int? может подскажите ресурсы где это можно почитать, потому что я сюда пишу уже после того как сам попытался найти информацию, но не нашел ее

Comment: @Andalexshap правильно поняли. Про `[index..]` это взять часть спана начиная с байта со смещением `index` и до конца. Если бы после `..` стояла другая переменная, она бы означала правую границу промежутка. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.range С массивами это тоже работает, с одной разницей, если использовать Range для массива, будет копирование данных, в случае со спаном - не будет.